# How do I debug dependencies which are integrated via conan?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, cmake, conan

I have recently converted a `C/C++` project to `cmake` and now get my dependencies which were previously part of the structure as submodules via `conan`.

Unfortunately, debugging no longer works so smoothly. I can still navigate to the header variables in the project without any problems inside my IDE.
These are now no longer in the project tree, but as expected in the conan home folder on the system, for example:

```
C:\.conan\447d7e\1\include\myheader.h
```

But in the IDE I can not longer navigate into the corresponding .c or .cpp files to set breakpoints. The IDE is unable to find them. Neither with something like `CTRL+Click` nor with `Rightclick+Go to...`.
Instead I have to search for these individually and open them in the IDE to be able to set breakpoints. This is very tedious, as the individual packages are not hidden behind human readable names in the file system, but behind folders which only have a hash value as a name.

So I wanted to ask whether it is somehow possible to bypass this indirection and improve debugging in a project with Conan dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Conan dependencies might be directly installed from a server with pre-compiled binaries, that means, the source folder is not even copied to the current computer.
Furthermore, the paths in the machine that created the binary are probably different to the machine consuming the binary, and some debug artifacts encode the full paths to the sources, so it is not straightforward to locate those sources, even if they were copied to the current machine (which is possible in Conan 2.0 with the `-c tools.build:download_source=True` configuration).

So the best option is to force a local build of the package you want to debug/step-into. When doing the `conan install` try:

```
conan install ... --build="pkgtodebug1/*" --build="pkgtodebug2/*" ...
```

That will build locally from source, and debuggers will find the sources and allow to step-in